# Simple, but fully-featured, Backbone example application?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm getting started with Backbone, and I'm hunting for an example application with no clutter but with all the key Backbone features: Routes, Models, Collections, Views and Events.

Ideally the application would have a workflow something like this:

- The application loads a list of article titles.
- The user clicks on an article title.
- The view changes slightly to update the URL and highlight that blog post.

Minimal and simple, but just showing how to use all the key elements, including Routes (which often seem to be omitted in examples, including [the official example](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#examples-todos)).

Basically I'd like something like the [sample code in this blog post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/), but (a) bulletproof and (b) with the HTML as well, so that I can copy, paste and start playing with it straight away.

Does anyone know of such an example?

Comment: You could (relatively) easily extrapolate the HTML code necessary based on the selectors used within that example.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now :) I just wondered if there was an existing example. Also, the blog post is a discussion about incorrect methods, so I'm slightly concerned that even the final code may not be the most bulletproof!

Comment: Yes, so copy/pasting that code into document.ready gives me errors right away, and I'm not enough of a Backbone buff to know how to fix them. The hunt continues...

Comment: Yes, a standard "backbone.js blog" is actually missing. However something nice can be found, try with https://github.com/oivoodoo/pomodoro-app

Comment: I'm using the Todos app for now, and will just try to work out routes for myself.

Comment: I'm using Backbone for my new blog... it's still a rough prototype and I'm still not sure on few things myself. That aside, it does demonstrates routes combined with HTML5 pushState. See the live site at http://test.cobbweb.me/ and source code on GitHub: https://github.com/cobbweb/cobbweb.me

Answer (score 3):

Might be [https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals (different example applications in "practicals" directory)](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals) is your required.

I am also new to backbone. But thanks to Addy Osmani (http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals), I got concepts and working code to understand backbone.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a blog, my [Backbone Store](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2011/08/08/backbone-store-version-20-regular-edition/) has all of the items you request, in a didactic, literate programming tutorial.  As an added bonus, there's also a Coffeescript/HAML/Stylus version on the same website.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial hugely useful while building my own single page App using Backbone.js...
http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/

There are additional parts that will get you started with CRUD features and fine-tuning etc.